# How to split multiple ComboBox entries into multiple lines in Sharepoint using PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

Below is a code I found on https://www.powerplatformguide.com/post/patching-combo-box-inputs-power-apps

This code splits Combobox2 multiple entries into multiple lines. How do I alter this code for multiple Combobox accepting multiple entries each? I would like different line items to be saved for each combination.

```
ForAll(
      Split(
            Concat(ComboBox2.SelectedItems,Value,", "),", "),
            Collect(boxCol,Result);
            
Patch(DS, Defaults(DS),
  {
      Name: Input_Name.Text,
      Age: Value(Input_Age.Text),
      'Date of Birth': Input_DOB.SelectedDate,
      'Favourite Car Brand': Dropdown_FavouriteCarBrand.Selected.Value,
      'Favourite Car Colour': Result
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with each combination?

An item has 2 Comboboxes.
Let's say, combobox 1 has the values A, B and C, and combobox 2 contains 1, 2, 3, and 4.
A user selects A and C from 1 and 2 and 3 from 2, you want the rows:
A2, A3, C2, C3?

If so,

```
ForAll( 
   ComboBox1.SelectedItems // this section will have A... B...
   ForAll(
      ComboBox2.SelectedItems // This Will Give A1, A2.... till the next iteration.
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But how does this "Collect(boxCol,Result);" change?

Because I can't use Result both times. How do I call these values below?

"'Favourite Car Colour': Result"

I tried Result1 , Result2, but that doesn't work.

Comment: ForAll(
    Combo1.SelectedItems,
    Collect(
        Demo,
        Concatenate(
            Combo2.SelectedItems,
            ThisRecord.Value
        )
    )
)

Combo1 is a box that contains A, B, C and D, Combo 2 contains 1, 2, 3 and 4. If I select 1, 2, A, B, C this gives the output 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, 2C.

This gets you started.